# View not resizing in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that has width `match_parent` with multiple pages, each filling a part of the screen. One of the pages has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. My `PagerAdapter` has the `getPageWidth()` method implemented to return 1 if there's just one view, and a percentage if there are more views. Nevertheless, that's not the problem. Trust me, I tested.

My problem is, when I remove the other view, this one doesn't fill the whole ViewPager, even if I create a new `PagerAdapter`. The only way this is solved is if I inflate the first view again.

Is there a way to solve this without inflating the view or the whole `ViewPager` each time I remove the second view?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

override this method

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    float page= 2; 
    return (1 / page);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `return 0.5;`?

Comment: I already stated that I overrode that method so that it returns a float depending if there is or isn't more than one view. Plus, how would setting the page width to 1/2 of the `ViewPager` solve my problem? Thanks for the help, though.